# Python. How to make a class so that I can create a set of related objects(like"Rock, Paper, Scissors") with it?

Tags: python

Python, please.

What I want to ask is that how to create the abstract objects(such as"Rock,paper,scissors") and compare them directly?

thanks.

```
#class Weapon:
   # pass

#rock = Weapon()
```

edited:

Sorry for the bad question. I didn't make myself clear.
I want some code like this:

```
class Weapon():
    def __init__(self, agr1[, agr2]):
        self.agr1 = agr1
        #self.agr2 = agr2
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        #if some condition:   
            return -1
        #if self == other:  
            return 0
        #if some condition:
            return 1

rock = Weapon(arg1, arg2)
scissors = Weapon(arg1, arg2)

#When it's done. It should look like this:
>>>rock > scissors
True
```

Comment: Will you please explain your answer in detail?

Comment: python itself is a dynamic language you can create interfaces implicitly. if you get the right objects you can just call their methods.

Comment: Questions asking for code should demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement comparisons between custom classes, you need to implement the [comparison magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#comparisons), e.g.:

```
def __gt__(self, other): # is self greater than other?
    return self.value > other.value # compare value attribute
```

However, If your class has no attributes, you are effectively trying to compare on the name the class instance is assigned to, which makes no sense. Instead, refactor your class:

```
class Weapon(object):

    def __init__(self, name, beats):
        self.name = name
        self.beats = beats

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return other.name in self.beats
```

Now you can create the weapons, e.g.

```
rock = Weapon("rock", ["scissors", "lizard"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Python class has inbuilt method `__eq__` which called when you compare 2 class object.

You have to override this method and check the value which you want to compare.